# Remove bullets add tick not working

Tags: html, css

I am trying to remove some bullets points, and replace them with ticks. I can make it work, but then my menu bar mess up. So I need to add a class to the `<ul>`, so it is not affecting anything else.

I tried to add a class, but still not working. Why?

Not working: [Not working](https://jsfiddle.net/ngfnx48f/)

Working but mess up my menu bar: [Working](https://jsfiddle.net/y4hv1d90/)

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="removeBulletAddTick">
    <li class="removeBulletAddTick"> Test text 1</li>
    <li class="removeBulletAddTick">Test text 2</li>
    <li class="removeBulletAddTick">Test text 3</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
ul removeBulletAddTick{
  list-style: none;
}

ul li:before {
  content: '✓';
}
```

**Update**

When I do your suggestion my menubar messed around:

[Screenshot of menubar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbeyF.jpg)

Comment: Did you mean to write `ul .removeBulletAddTick`?

Comment: Thank you for the answer @WanderNauta. I just updated my question.

Comment: It needs to be ul.removeBulletAddTick as the class and tag are in the same line.  No space between the ul and class name.

Comment: The JSFiddle isn't working for you since you haven't declared your *class* selector properly - you're just missing the period (`.`) before the selector. It should be `.removeBulletAddTick`. Updated JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ngfnx48f/3/

Comment: beautiful - Working lige a charm @UncaughtTypeError. Can you lay an answer, so I can close the question?

Comment: Sure. Would be happy to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out, the *class* selector wasn't declared correctly, it was missing the period (`.`) and should be `.removeBulletAddTick`.

The code below demonstrates this, you'll notice the class in question added to the list item rules as well for more specificity - this is to ensure that these rules will only apply to the list items you intend them to; which are those with the classes `.removeBulletAddTick`.

```
ul .removeBulletAddTick {
  list-style: none;
}

ul li.removeBulletAddTick:before {
  content: '✓';
}
```

[Updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ngfnx48f/3/)

You don't even need to declare that class on *every* list item. It would be better to declare it on the containing parent element, as follows:

```
ul.removeBulletAddTick {
  list-style: none;
}

ul.removeBulletAddTick li:before {
  content: '✓';
}
```

**Code Snippet Demonstration:**

```css
ul.removeBulletAddTick {
  list-style: none;
}

ul.removeBulletAddTick li:before {
  content: '✓';
}
```

```html
<ul class="removeBulletAddTick">
    <li>Test text 1</li>
    <li>Test text 2</li>
    <li>Test text 3</li>
</ul>
```